# Genuine command is not recognized in Windows via PHP's exec

Tags: php, mysql, windows, exec

Problem:-

I am trying to backup MySQL database using PHP and mysqldump in **windows**. The following script gives a dump as desired *with flying colours* when I use wamp server.

```
<?php
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = '';
   $dbname = 'avita';
   $path = "c:/program files/mysql/mysql server 5.5/bin/";
   $backup_file = "d:/avita/".$dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.sql';
   $command = $path."mysqldump -u$dbuser ". "avita 2>&1 $backup_file";

   exec($command, $output);
   print_r($output);
?>
```

The same can be done using **windows command line** without any problem:-

[image]

The **problem** is that when I run the same script in the same machine with PHP-MySQL-Apache manual installation, the output is something like below:-

**Output:-**

> Array ( [0] => 'c:/program' is not **recognized as an internal or**
>   **external command,** [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjXPJ.jpg) => **operable program or batch file**. )

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Try using [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) on all the parameters  and paths (full path to mysqldump, including "mysqldump").

Comment: @Vatev, Thank you for your suggestion. It works. But it works only if I replace 2>&1 with > and can't figure out the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of overlapping misunderstandings.

1. `%PATH%` (or `$PATH` in *nix environments).  The only reason your manual command line works is because you have already changed to the MySQL directory, and Windows checks the *current* directory.  Try running `mysqldump` (just as you have above, without any directory qualifiers) when your prompt reads simply:

   ```
   C:\>
   ```

   What happened?  It didn't work, but why?
2. Next, recall that PHP's `exec()` is a thin wrapper around the shell.  Let's pretend you are running the shell being given the script above.  Lacking a known directory, let's assume we're in the root:

   ```
   C:\>c:/program files/mysql/mysql server 5.5/bin/mysqldump.exe
   `c:/program` is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file
   ```

   Exact same issue!  ... So what happened?  Quoting.  The shell interprets spaces as token delimiters, so the shell complains that `c:/program` is not a valid executable.  Try it with quotes, and now the shell understands the entire "weird" path with spaces is all the first argument and actually the path to the executable we want:

   ```
   C:\>"c:/program files/mysql/mysql server 5.5/bin/mysqldump.exe"
   ```

   And suddenly it worked as expected!
3. PHP has a series of "paper cuts," and one of those is "sane" handling of executables like this.  PHP is C-like here in that you have to do the escaping yourself.  Consider:

   ```
   $command_parts = [
     escapeshellarg("${path}mysqldump.exe"),
     escapeshellarg("-u$dbuser"),
     "avita",    # no escapeshellarg here, as avita is visually "clean"
     "2>&1",     # no escapeshellarg here, as 2>&1 is visually "clean"
     escapeshellarg($backup_file)
   ];
   $command = implode(' ', $command_parts);
   exec( $command );
   ```

And from here, your script should work as expected.